# 2sxc | Default Value of Page Picker to be current page?

Tags: 2sxc

Is it possible to have the Page Picker input hyperlink field to have a default value be the current page? I know you can specify a selected page but if this was automized then it would aid UX, thx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible yet. A future version of 2sxc (ca. 9.12 or 9.15) will change page-picking forever :). We will create a PagesDataSource which will then allow for very flexible setups - incl. special filters, queries etc.

So we won't add any more features to page-picking till that is out.